# New to PDO, how to write correctly this SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PDO and my question is, should I escape the $input before adding it to the query? How should I implement it at it's best?

```
$input= $_POST['time']; //2012-07-21 17:00:00

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM events WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , TIME, $input ) < 2') as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: You're using it, that's what you're doing wrong. Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: The result is `false` and not printed with echo. The result is false probably because you don't have a connection to the database. And using it in the first place is wrong as well. :d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you would wan't to use PDO::quote() although you should use prepared statements, It's one of the major reasons why you do the switch to mysqli or PDO.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user','pass');

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , TIME, :input ) < 2');
$query->bindValue(":input", $input, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. So, PDO does not need any escapes like the mysql real escape string, right?

Comment: It depends, I guess a good rule of thumb is whenever you "manually" concatenate strings into a query you need to escape. If you use prepared statements you do not. PDOs equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string is PDO::quote(), $string = $db->quote($string). Besides escaping it also adds quotes so you should only use it on strings. On numbers you should just use type casting, $safe_int = (int)$presumably_safe_int.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with truth.

though to answer your question mysql_real_escape_string() needs an active connection to work. if you had not open any connection to database it will not work else it will take the last opened connection unless you specify the connection explicitly.